# Make parenthesis the first priority on an arithmetic expression on TAC

Tags: java, c++, math, logic

So I have here my code implementing Three Address Code in arithmetic expression.

```
class ThreeAddressCode {

private static final char[][] precedence = {
    {'/', '1'},
    {'*', '1'},
    {'+', '2'},
    {'-', '2'}
};
private static int precedenceOf(String t)
{
    char token = t.charAt(0);
    for (int i=0; i < precedence.length; i++)
    {
        if (token == precedence[i][0])
        {
            return Integer.parseInt(precedence[i][1]+"");
        }
    }
    return -1;
}

public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception
{
    int i, j, opc=0;
    char token;
    boolean processed[];
    String[][] operators = new String[10][2];
    String expr="", temp;
    BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
    System.out.print("\nEnter an expression: ");
    expr = in.readLine();
    processed = new boolean[expr.length()];
    for (i=0; i < processed.length; i++)
    {
        processed[i] = false;
    }
    for (i=0; i < expr.length(); i++)
    {
        token = expr.charAt(i);
        for (j=0; j < precedence.length; j++)
        {
            if (token==precedence[j][0])
            {
                operators[opc][0] = token+"";
                operators[opc][1] = i+"";
                opc++;
                break;
            }
        }
    }
    System.out.println("\nOperators:\nOperator\tLocation");
    for (i=0; i < opc; i++)
    {
        System.out.println(operators[i][0] + "\t\t" + operators[i][1]);
    }
    //sort
    for (i=opc-1; i >= 0; i--)
    {
        for (j=0; j < i; j++)
        {
            if (precedenceOf(operators[j][0]) > precedenceOf(operators[j+1][0]))
            {
                temp = operators[j][0];
                operators[j][0] = operators[j+1][0];
                operators[j+1][0] = temp;
                temp = operators[j][1];
                operators[j][1] = operators[j+1][1];
                operators[j+1][1] = temp;
            }               
        }
    }
    System.out.println("\nOperators sorted in their precedence:\nOperator\tLocation");
    for (i=0; i < opc; i++)
    {
        System.out.println(operators[i][0] + "\t\t" + operators[i][1]);
    }
    System.out.println();
    for (i=0; i < opc; i++)
    {
        j = Integer.parseInt(operators[i][1]+"");
        String op1="", op2="";
        if (processed[j-1]==true)
        {
            if (precedenceOf(operators[i-1][0]) == precedenceOf(operators[i][0]))
            {
                op1 = "t"+i;
            }
            else
            {
                for (int x=0; x < opc; x++)
                {
                    if ((j-2) == Integer.parseInt(operators[x][1]))
                    {
                        op1 = "t"+(x+1)+"";
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        else
        {
            op1 = expr.charAt(j-1)+"";
        }
        if (processed[j+1]==true)
        {
            for (int x=0; x < opc; x++)
            {
                if ((j+2) == Integer.parseInt(operators[x][1]))
                {
                    op2 = "t"+(x+1)+"";
                }
            }
        }
        else
        {
            op2 = expr.charAt(j+1)+"";
        }
        System.out.println("t"+(i+1)+" = "+op1+operators[i][0]+op2);
        processed[j] = processed[j-1] = processed[j+1] = true;
    }
}
}
```

**Sample Output**

Input : a * b / c

t1 = a * b

t2 = t1 / c

What the program does is evaluate the arithmetic expression and shows them step by step by operators.

Can you help me to include parenthesis in the priorities? and achieve an output like this

**Sample Output**

Input : a * ( b + c )

t1 = b + c

t2 = a * t2

Right now, the parenthesis is treated like an operand.

Comment: Throw it all away and look up the Dijkstra Shunting-yard algorithm.

Answer (score 0):

I did not use any of your code. Sorry.

This was a fun one to think about. I have never considered how you would do something like this. It does not follow all of the best practices to a "T", but the question inspired me to consider how you would do this in a rudimentary way.

You could make much of this code smaller by using more Java Frameworks, but it was enjoyable to strictly try to work this out logically.

This code is missing most validation (i.e. The user inputs an erroneous expression)

It does however check if there are an equal number of open and close parenthesis.

Lastly, I had to wrap things up so I did not extend into expressions with nested parenthesis.

Example a * ( b * ( c / d ) - e ) >> this code does not handle this scenario, and would have to be enhanced to accommodate for this.

Otherwise, it should give a pretty good idea as to one way you could go about building a program to work through parenthesis.

I hope it helps

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.List;

public class MathPriority {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        String expression = "a * (b * c) + (d / e)"; //You can work out how you want input to com in
        List<String> priorityList = getPriorityList(expression);//Find parenthesis and sets priority.
        expression = expression.replace(" ", "").replace("(", "").replace(")", "");//Take out any spaces and parenthesis

        for (int i = 0; i < priorityList.size(); i++) {//Replaces the piece in parenthesis with var and outputs var           
            expression = expression.replace(priorityList.get(i), "t" + (i + 1));
            System.out.println("t" + (i + 1) + " = " + priorityList.get(i));
        }
        System.out.println("t" + (priorityList.size() + 1) + " = " + expression);//pushes final variable set
    }
    //You can use this to build a List of indexes of a character within a String
    public static List<Integer> getAllOccurencesOfChar(List<String> expression, String indexO) {      
        List<Integer> parIndexList = new ArrayList<>();
        for (int i = 0; i < expression.size(); i++) {
            if (expression.get(i).contains(indexO)) {
                if (!parIndexList.contains(i) && i > 0) {
                    parIndexList.add(i);
                }
            }
        }
        return parIndexList;
    }
    //Outputs a list of substrings. They can later be used to parse through the inital string
    public static List<String> getPriorityList(String expression) {

        List<String> priorityList = new ArrayList<>();
        expression = expression.replace(" ", "");
        String[] eParts = expression.split("");
        List<String> expressionParts = new ArrayList<>();//Get expression into single chars
        for (String e : eParts) {//If you change this to an Array.List, it will not work. This type of list is fixed in size
            expressionParts.add(e);
        }
        List<Integer> parIndexList = getAllOccurencesOfChar(expressionParts, "(");//find all open paranthesis
        List<Integer> rParIndexList = getAllOccurencesOfChar(expressionParts, ")");//find all close paranthesis

        if (parIndexList.size() != rParIndexList.size()) {
            System.out.println("Your Equation does not have an equal number of open and close parenthesis");
            System.exit(0);
        }

        //Work out the parenthesis
        int loopIterator = parIndexList.size();//This will change as we iterate
        for (int pars = loopIterator - 1; pars >= 0; pars--) {

            int start = parIndexList.get(pars); //Define a start
            int end = 0;                        //and End
            //int end = rParIndexList.get(pars);

            for (int contemplate = 0; contemplate < loopIterator; contemplate++) {//contemplate where given parenthesis starts and where its closing tag is
                if (parIndexList.get(pars) < rParIndexList.get(contemplate)) {
                    end = rParIndexList.get(contemplate);//find first occurence and set true end
                    break;//then stop
                }
            }

            String expre = "";
            for (int concat = start + 1; concat < end; concat++) {
                expre += expressionParts.get(concat);//put the priorityList's subExpression together
            }

            priorityList.add(expre);//add that subExpression to the list
            expressionParts.subList(start, end + 1).clear();//remove these expressionParts

            /*Re-establish where the parenthesis are, since we removed parts of the expression in the list*/
            parIndexList = getAllOccurencesOfChar(expressionParts, "(");//find all open paranthesis
            rParIndexList = getAllOccurencesOfChar(expressionParts, ")");//find all close paranthesis
            loopIterator = parIndexList.size();//resize the forLoop
        }

        return priorityList;

    }

    public static List<Integer> getStartEndPosition(String fullExpression, String subExpression) {
        List<Integer> sAndE = new ArrayList<>();

        String[] eParts = subExpression.split("");
        List<String> wordParts = new ArrayList<>();
        wordParts.addAll(Arrays.asList(eParts));
        /*Find multiples of same operand*/
        List<Integer> add = getAllOccurencesOfChar(wordParts, "+");
        List<Integer> subtract = getAllOccurencesOfChar(wordParts, "-");
        List<Integer> divide = getAllOccurencesOfChar(wordParts, "/");
        List<Integer> multiply = getAllOccurencesOfChar(wordParts, "*");

        /*Find single Operands*/
        int plus = subExpression.indexOf("+");
        int minus = subExpression.indexOf("-");
        int div = subExpression.indexOf("/");
        int mult = subExpression.indexOf("*");

        int multiOperands = plus + minus + div + mult;//See if multiples exist
        int startingPosition = 0;

        if (add.size() > 1 || subtract.size() > 1 || divide.size() > 1 || multiply.size() > 1
                || multiOperands > 0) {
            //expression has multiple opreands of different types
            String findStart = wordParts.get(0) + wordParts.get(1);
            String findEnd = wordParts.get(wordParts.size() - 2) + wordParts.get(wordParts.size() - 1);
            startingPosition = fullExpression.indexOf(findStart);
            sAndE.add(startingPosition);
            int endPosition = fullExpression.indexOf(findEnd);
            sAndE.add(endPosition);

        } else {

            startingPosition = fullExpression.indexOf(subExpression);
            sAndE.add(startingPosition);
            sAndE.add(startingPosition + subExpression.length());

        }

        return sAndE;
    }

}
```

> String expression = "a * (b * c) + (d / e)"

**Outputs:**

```
t1 = d/e
t2 = b*c
t3 = a*t2+t1
```